# Why this copy-constructor is invoked in the program?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

class withCC
{
public:
    withCC() {}
    withCC(const withCC&) {
        cout<<"withCC(withCC&)"<<endl;
    }
};

class woCC
{
    enum {bsz = 100};
    char buf[bsz];
public:
    woCC(const char* msg = 0) {
        memset(buf, 0, bsz);
        if(msg) strncpy(buf, msg, bsz);
    }
    void print(const char* msg = 0)const {
        if(msg) cout<<msg<<":";
        cout<<buf<<endl;
    }
};

class composite
{
    withCC WITHCC;
    woCC WOCC;
public:
    composite() : WOCC("composite()") {}
    void print(const char* msg = 0) {
        cout<<"in composite:"<<endl;
        WOCC.print(msg);
    }
};

int main()
{
    composite c;
    c.print("contents of c");
    cout<<"calling composite copy-constructor"<<endl;
    composite c2 = c;
    c2.print("contents of c2");
}
```

The running result is below:

```
$ ./a.out 
in composite:
contents of c:composite()
calling composite copy-constructor
withCC(withCC&)
in composite:
contents of c2:composite()
```

And I don't understand why `withCC(withCC&)` is given as part of output. I guess `composite c2 = c;` causes copy-constructor to be executed. But as below shown, `WITHCC` is part of `class composite`, why it will be invoked to handle this copy-constructor? Thanks!

Comment: Because a copy needs to be made?

Comment: @AshRj: I don't think this is quite a duplicate: here the user wonders about the behavior of copy constructors w.r.t. composition, not inheritance.

Comment: @MrFooz My mistake. Removed link.

Comment: @MrFooz Although answer is the same, by-design.

Comment: @AshRj: agreed that the solution is the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The copy constructor `withCC(withCC&)` was invoked because the default copy constructor of `composite` will call all copy constructors of it's member data.  And since you have a `withCC` object as a member data in the `composite` class, the copy constructor `withCC(withCC&)` is called.

Answer (score 2):

Copy constructor is called

- When instantiating one object and initializing it with values from another object or
- When ever you pass an object by value as an argument to a function or
- return the object by value from the function

The default copy constructor of `composite` class will call the copy constructor of its members, that's why `withCC(withCC&)` is getting printed.

Comment: No, `Foo f2 = f;` does not invoke `operator=`, it invokes a copy constructor.  It may look like `=`, but it is actually construction.

Comment: @Yakk I mentioned that when objects are passed to a function, the copy constructor is invoked. In this case the function is the = overloading function

Comment: `operator=` on `composite` objects is never, ever called in the original poster's code.  No interaction with `operator=` occurs that involves `withCC(const withCC&)`.

Answer (score 1):

statement **composite c2 = c;**
will try to copy the object through **copy constructor** but class **composite** does not have user defined copy constructor hence default copy constructor of compiler will be used in your case.
And you want to construct **WOCC** object also with the creation of **composite** hence for **WOCC** construction the **user define copy constructor of with cc** gets called